# Getting audio from certain audio sources as buffer in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, streaming, photon, mixer

I am making a game in which I need to stream SOME of the audio to other players. Right now I am using OnAudioFIlterRead() on the AudioListener to get ALL audio as a buffer, and I have managed to stream this using Photon Voice.

However, I only want to stream certain audio sources (about 18) which make up the music part of my music game. There will also be voice chat (which is streamed separately) and maybe other audio sources that I do not want to stream.

I could assign these audio clips to a mixer track, but I have not found a way to get audio from a mixer track as a buffer? Does anyone have a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: To my knowledge, `OnAudioFilterRead` does not work with the new audio system. You can read from individual `AudioSources` using the old system and write your own mixer, however.

Comment: @Lece Thanks for the response, I was thinking about this, but I thought it might be quite complex.. I am not sure what the process of layering the audio sources into a single buffer would be.. would summing the values of each audio source achieve this or just a horrible mess of noise?

Comment: Summing would only increase output gain which can easily be scaled back. And yes, managing buffers across threads will certainly need some careful planning. :)